# Rendering Contextual Links after AJAX refresh

Tags: ajax, flags, javascript, navigation

We have written a small module that would allow teasers in views reload/refreshed when flagged from inside the contextual links.

The names of the flags are '*sold*', '*underoffer*' and '*withdraw*'.

The reloading/resfreshing of the teasers works beautifully! But after refreshing of the teaser the **little cog of Contextual Links disappears**. I can see the dom generated, but it seems like it is not rendered properly as being "active".  And I really need the Contextual Links to re-appear as expected.

Below is the code for refresh_teaser.module and refresh_teaser.js (inside the js folder) :

**refresh_teaser.module:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements of hook_init()
 * @param: NULL
 * @return: NULL
 */
function refresh_teaser_init() {
  // Including the custom jquery file for teaser refresh functionality.
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'refresh_teaser') .
        '/js/refresh_teaser.js');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_flag_javascript_info_alter().
 */
function refresh_teaser_flag_javascript_info_alter(&$info) {
  // Passing the teaser view content to the javascript file refresh_teaser.js.
  $content_id = $info['contentId'];
  $node = node_load($content_id);
  $view_full = node_view($node, 'full');
  $view = node_view($node, 'teaser');
  $rendered_full = drupal_render($view_full);
  $rendered = drupal_render($view);
  $info['rendered_node_full'] = $rendered_full;
  $info['rendered_node'] = $rendered;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter().
 */
function refresh_teaser_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if (!empty($build['#node']->nid)) {
    $build['#contextual_links']['node'] = array('node', array($build['#node']->nid));
  }
}
```

**refresh_teaser.js** (inside it's own 'js' folder):

```
// Drupal JS file document.ready functions
// Jquery wrapper for drupal to avoid conflicts between libraries.
(function ($) {

  $(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {
    var node_id = data.contentId;
    var rendered_teaser = data.rendered_node;
    var rendered_full_node = data.rendered_node_full;

    // Create the array of flag to be checked.
    var flags_req = ["underoffer", "sold", "withdraw"];
    var recent_flag = data.flagName;

    // 
    if ($.inArray(recent_flag, flags_req) !== -1) {
      // Check if the view is teaser than only replace the content.
      if ($('#node-'+node_id).hasClass("node-teaser")) {
        // Refreshing the content of the teaser.
        $('#node-'+node_id).replaceWith(function() {
          return $(rendered_teaser).hide().fadeIn();
        });
      }
      else if ($('#node-'+node_id).hasClass("node-full")) {
        console.log(rendered_full_node);
        // Refresh the content of full view.
        $('#node-'+node_id).replaceWith(function() {
          return $(rendered_full_node).hide().fadeIn();
        });
      }
    }  
  });

  Drupal.refresh_teaser = Drupal.refresh_teaser || {};

/**
 * Attaches outline behavior for regions associated with contextual links.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.refresh_teaser = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $('div.contextual-links-wrapper', context).once('contextual-links', function () {
      var $wrapper = $(this);
      var $region = $wrapper.closest('.contextual-links-region');
      var $links = $wrapper.find('ul.contextual-links');
      var $trigger = $('<a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#" />').text(Drupal.t('Configure')).click(
        function () {
          $links.stop(true, true).slideToggle(100);
          $wrapper.toggleClass('contextual-links-active');
          return false;
        }
      );
      // Attach hover behavior to trigger and ul.contextual-links.
      $trigger.add($links).hover(
        function () { $region.addClass('contextual-links-region-active'); },
        function () { $region.removeClass('contextual-links-region-active'); }
      );
      // Hide the contextual links when user clicks a link or rolls out of the .contextual-links-region.
      $region.bind('mouseleave click', Drupal.refresh_teaser.mouseleave);
      // Prepend the trigger.
      $wrapper.prepend($trigger);
    });
  }
};

/**
 * Disables outline for the region contextual links are associated with.
 */
Drupal.contextualLinks.mouseleave = function () {
  $(this)
    .find('.contextual-links-active').removeClass('contextual-links-active')
    .find('ul.contextual-links').hide();
};

})(jQuery);
```

Take this code and make it into "refresh_teaser" module. (The .js file should be placed in side "js" folder inside the module.) Please test it and you can see it in action on a fresh install. Just create a 3 flags with machine names: '*sold*' , '*underoffer*' and '*withdraw*' , and in flag settings make them appear inside contextual links, and set them to JS toggle. You will see that after flagging the teaser refreshes, but the **Contextual Links cog disappears**.  And I really-really need those Contextual Links to re-appear as normal!

Can someone please help?

Comment: is there any solution to your problem?